# what does "nearest" in this sense mean?

Tags: vocabulary

coming next after somebody/something
I am wondering what **near** means here.

She has a 12-point lead over her nearest rival.

**UPDATED: What does"lead" mean here?**
 Extracted from:

[enter link description here](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/near_1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, 'nearest' refers to person who is closest to the subject in terms of the points they scored. So, the person who is 'nearest' to the subject is just next on the scoreboard.
For example, in a race, the person nearest to whoever came first, would be the person who came second.

Here, 'lead' refers to amount of points the subject has scored more than the person just behind her. For example let us assume that the winner scored 50 points, and that she had a 12-point lead. This means that the person who came second scored 12 points less than her, that is, 38 points.

Comment: Thank you all so much . I got it through your invaluable explanations.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, "lead" means the number of points different between the subject and the person that scored the closest. For example, the hypothetical score board for the example could look like this:

> Subject of sentence: 36 points
>
> Rival: 24 points
>
> Other: 20 points

Note: "Rival" is the subject's "nearest rival" because 36 (Subject's score) is closer to 24 (Rival's score).

Comment: Nice math, but completely unnecessary. If Subject has a "**lead** over her rival", you are automatically comparing with someone behind her, otherwise she couldn't lead.

Comment: So true! Updating my example to be more useful.